# How can I make a right "hanging" from last line of a paragraph?

Tags: xetex

How can I make a right "hanging" from last line of a paragraph?
This is useful for tables of content and indexes with long entries.

The following is an example of what I need:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ........................... 123

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit.  Ut  purus  elit, vestibulum  ut, placerat ac
adipiscing  vitae, felis. Curabitur  dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna. .............................. 456

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ........................... 789
```

At the moment I'm using the following. But it justifies the text and the numbers at the same right position:
`\par\noindent\raggedright very long text \dotfill 456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way, your task is to adapt it for TOC entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\specialpar}[2]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{1ex}
  \begingroup
  \hangafter=0
  \hangindent=-6em
  \parfillskip=-6em
  \noindent#1\dotfill#2\par
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{1ex}
}

\begin{document}

\specialpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{123}

\specialpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit.  Ut  purus  elit, vestibulum  ut, placerat ac
adipiscing  vitae, felis. Curabitur  dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna.}{456}

\specialpar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{789}

\end{document}
```

[image]